# Double Integral Over Triangular region using change of variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate this double integral

$\iint_R(x-3y)\,dA$ where $R$ is a triangular region with the vertices $(0,0)$, $(2,1)$, and $(1,2)$ and $x = 2u+v$ and $y=u+2v$.

Knowing that $y = 2x$, $u+2v=4u+2v$, so $u=0$. And $y=\frac{1}{2}x$ so $u+2v=u+\frac{1}{2}v$ so $v=0$. But the last relationship, $y=-x+3$, giving us $v=3-3u$. I don't know where to go from here regarding finding the bounds for the integrals.The jacobian here is 3.

Comment: Just figure out where the vertices map to.

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: This is an affine (linear, even) mapping from the $x$-$y$ plane to the $u$-$v$ plane.  So a triangle will map to a triangle.  If you figure out where the three vertices map to, that'll get you the vertices of the triangular region in the $u$-$v$ plane.

Comment: so how do you do that?

Comment: Plug your three points into $x$ and $y$ in your two equations and solve for $u$ and $v$.  For instance, plugging $(0,0)$ in gets you $$\begin{cases} 0=2u+v \\ 0=u+2v\end{cases}$$ Use linear algebra, or high school algebra, to solve for $u$ and $v$.  Then do the same for the other two points.

Comment: so then is your final answer -9? I want clarification because i think this answer key i have is wrong

Comment: [I get $-3$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double+integral&a=*MC.~-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=3(2u%2Bv-3u-6v)&f=DoubleIntegral.integrand_3(2u%2Bv-3u-6v)&f3=u&f=DoubleIntegral.intvariable1_u&f4=0&f=DoubleIntegral.rangestart1%5Cu005f0&f5=1&f=DoubleIntegral.rangeend1%5Cu005f1&f6=v&f=DoubleIntegral.intvariable2_v&f7=0&f=DoubleIntegral.rangestart2%5Cu005f0&f8=1-u&f=DoubleIntegral.rangeend2_1-u).

Comment: are you bounds $0 \leq v \leq 1$ and $0 \leq u \leq 1$

Comment: That's a square, not a [triangle](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=triangle+with+vertices+%280%2C0%29+%281%2C0%29+%280%2C1%29).

Comment: Great, thanks for all the help